# Is it possible to make a button scrollable inside a canvas?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've been trying to make a button inside the canvas scrollable but it wont scroll.

I've tried placing it inside ListBox,canvas,frame it didn't work. I've tried doing everything but still don't know what to do at this point.

```
from tkinter import *

FrameU = Tk()
frameN=Frame(FrameU,width=540,height=800,bg="#A0522D")
frameN.place(x=0,y=0,relx=.2,rely=.2)
canvas=Canvas(frameN,bg="#A0522D",width=400,height=800)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frameN, orient = VERTICAL,width=20,relief=SUNKEN)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(width=540,height=800,relief=SUNKEN)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)



mylist=Listbox(canvas,bg="#A0522D",width=100,height=41,bd=5,highlightthickness=0,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set )
for i in range(100):
    mylist.insert(END, i)

b = Button(canvas,bg="blue",width=5,height=5)
b.place(rely=.5,relx=.5)

mylist.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
mylist.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT)
```

I don't get any errors or anything but if I place it inside my Listbox it shows inside in "for i in range(100):" it shows inside the canvas ".!frame.!canvas.!listbox.!button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrollable button. You mean a position of a button changes with the scrollbar slider moving? At a first glance in a simplest case it looks like it's impossible.

But you can bind a callback function to your scrollbar, and this function will change the button position synchronously with the scrollbars slider moving by a mouse. Here is a working example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

rx, ry = 0.45, 0.45           # the button position (relative)

root=Tk()

wCanvas, hCanvas = 400, 350   # size of canvas
w1, h1 = 800, 700             # size of scrollable area

vBar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient = VERTICAL)
can1 = Canvas(root, scrollregion = (0,0,w1,h1), width = wCanvas, height = hCanvas, yscrollcommand = vBar.set)
vBar['command'] = can1.yview

vBar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
can1.pack()

can1.create_line(10, 10, 100, 100)   # for canvas scrolling confirmation only

but1 = Button(can1)
but1.place(relx = rx, rely = ry)

def VscrollBarMove(event):  # callback function
    but1.place(relx = rx, rely = ry + vBar.get()[0])  # Scrollbar.get() returns a tuple with relative positions of upper (for vertical scrollbar) and lower edges of a slider

vBar.bind('<B1-Motion>', VscrollBarMove)

root.mainloop()
```

Version of the callback function for the 2-button case:

```
def VscrollBarMove(event):  # callback function
    but1.place(relx = rx, rely=ry+vBar.get()[0])
    but2.place(rely = ry2 + vBar.get()[0])  # You can set the only desirable coordinate if You want
```

Comment: I like the answer and I've tried it out. It worked good however, im a little confused. If I wanted to add more buttons what do I need to change or add. I've tried to add another button however the button's position wouldn't change, only the 1dt button's position changes.

Comment: All of You need - to add the processing of the second (and next it they exist) button to the same callback function. I added the example for this case to my answer.

Comment: I have 1 more question. When I scroll, the button goes down with it. How can I change directions for the button to go up while im scrolling down?

Comment: You need to change the operation in rely=ry+vBar.get()[0] from "+" to "-".  You even can change the direction of movement if you will process "relx" instead "rely".

Comment: In line:12. For can1. For scrollregion can I make the width = 0 if im not wanting to scroll side ways or is that for something else?

Comment: Parameter _width_ designate the width of canvas itself. Theoretically, you can set it to 0, you will get a very narrow (zero-width) canvas in this case and I doubt that it is that you want.  You can reorder parameters in the Canvas constructor for clarity, for example `can1 = Canvas(root, width = wCanvas, height = hCanvas, scrollregion = (0,0,w1,h1), yscrollcommand = vBar.set)`. Also you can use here `scrollregion = (0,0,0,h1)`, and probably it is that you want.

Comment: Hello im back I have a problem. My h1 is set to 4000 and my hCanvas is 700. For somereason my scrollreagion height wont go more down than 4000. It will make the scrollbar look like it has alot more down but it really doesnt I need fixed please if you need any extra info ill send you some of my code

Comment: Do I copy and paste my code in comments or how can I avoid characters being all used, up cuz my code has over 2000 words.

Comment: Can you get a short example concerned with the Canvas, Scrollbar and your problem only? Or it will be simpler to start the new question with this problem and (almost) full code.

Comment: I can but the Issue is its gonna be missing all the buttons that are placed inside it which I believe could be the problem but im really not sure. I believe starting a new question will be easier. I will send you the link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188091/scrollregions-height-wont-go-more-than-4000