# Scrollregions height won't go more than 4000

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My scrollregion height won't go any more than 4000. It doesn't change the height when I set it to 10000.

I've tried to change the Canvas height by adding 100+ to it

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
FrameU = Tk()


FrameNU=Frame(FrameU,width=540,height=800,bg="#A0522D")
FrameNU.place(x=0,y=0,relx=.2,rely=.2)

rx = .5
ry = .5

wCanvas, hCanvas = 550, 700   # size of canvas
w1, h1 = 0, 4000             # size of scrollable area

vBar = ttk.Scrollbar(FrameNU, orient = VERTICAL)
canvas_Main = Canvas(FrameNU,bg="#A0522D" ,scrollregion = (0,0,w1,h1), width = wCanvas, height = hCanvas, yscrollcommand = vBar.set)
vBar['command'] = canvas_Main.yview

vBar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
canvas_Main.pack()

canvas_Main.create_line(10, 10, 100, 100)  #Test if it works
#Buttons setup below over 160... Only added 1
MS = Button(canvas_Main,height=3,width=6,bg="blue")

def VscrollBarMove(event):
    MS.place(relx = rx, rely = ry - vBar.get()[0]) 
    #... More placements just added one


vBar.bind('<B1-Motion>', VscrollBarMove)
mainloop()
```

No errors. When I changed the height from 4000 to 10000 it didn't change anything but made the scrollbar look smaller as if it had more area going down but it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't have "more area going down"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct in the sense of the Python (and the Tkinter) syntax. I modified it slightly to proof it's correctness. (Of course, all of new lines are not obligatory.)
1. Let's open the window to a full screen:

```
FrameU = Tk()   # The existing string
windowHeight = FrameU.winfo_screenheight()
windowWidth = FrameU.winfo_screenwidth()
FrameU.geometry('{}x{}'.format(windowWidth, windowHeight))
FrameU.state('zoomed')
```

2. I changed the vertical position of the second frame for full view of the vertical scrollbar (on my current 1280 x 768 screen):

```
FrameNU.place(x=0,y=0,relx=.2,rely=.05)  # the old rely was 0.2
```

3. New variable for the big canvas:

```
w1, h1 = 0, 4000    # size of scrollable area  # the exisiting string
h2 = 10000          # the new variable
```

4. And we use this new variable instead h1:

```
canvas_Main = Canvas(FrameNU, ... ,scrollregion = (0,0,w1,h2), ... )  # Here h2 - the only change
```

5. Reference lines for the scrollbar correct behavior proof, as *Bryan Oakley* adviced.

```
canvas_Main.create_line(10, h1-5, 100, h1-5, fill = 'green')  
canvas_Main.create_line(10, h2-5, 100, h2-5, fill = 'blue')   # before VscrollBarMove function definition
```

That's all.

Comment: It did work but only gave me a tiny bit of space. Like a inch. going from 4k to 10k seems like it should have gave me enough space but it barely did.

Comment: @Mike: are you _sure_ you're talking about the scrolling region and not about the visible portion of the canvas? Quite literally, going from 4k to 10k is a difference of 6,000 pixels. At 100dpi that's the equivalent of 60 inches of scrollable space. It doesn't change the visible space at all, however.

Comment: I believe the visible portion of the canvas

Answer (score 0):

> When I changed the height from 4000 to 10000 it didnt change anything but made the scrollbar look smaller as if it had more area going down but it doesn't.

That's precisely what changing the `scrollregion` does. It changes the part of the canvas that can be scrolled into view, which in turn affects how the thumb of the scrollbar is drawn. It doesn't matter whether you've drawn in that region or not.

You can see that it works by setting the height to 10000, and then drawing something at y coordinate 9000. When you scroll, that item will come into view.

Comment: Ok so I looked closer and it did give more space but and the same time it barely didn't as I was expecting.

Comment: @Mike: I don't understand what you mean by "barely didn't". Going from 4000 to 10000 will literally add 6000 pixels to the region that you're able to scroll.